# Getting menu item selected from Twitter Bootstrap dropdown

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Am I misunderstanding Bootstraps's documentation?

> **hide.bs.dropdown**
>
> This event is fired immediately when the hide instance method has been
>   called. The toggling anchor element is available as the relatedTarget
>   property of the event.

Using the documentations own markup + code http://jsfiddle.net/ag8cdqok/ you can see the `relatedTarget` is the button, not the anchor.

How could I find out which item in the list was selected?

Comment: Documentation is correct: *The **toggling** anchor element is available as the relatedTarget property of the event.* Emphasis on toggling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<button>` is the toggling element (toggles the class ".open"). This element could be an `<a>` or `<span>` or any containable element . Documentation is correct.
To target the element that was selected you have to bind an other event:

```
$(".dropdown-menu").on('click', 'li a', function(){
      console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: This is what I to resorted to, thanks for the response